# Stacking a corner of a div underneath another div

Tags: html, css, z-index

I am trying to put the corner of the blue square div under the orange div. I tried everything I know:
`z-index` doesn't work because my div is wrapped in another div, and if I unwrap it I will have a trouble with positioning eight elements.

Can someone tell me how to do this? Or how to use z-index for all elements?

What I have:

[image: one]

What I need:

[image: two]

My HTML so far:

```css
 body {
   background-color: #222;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
 #blueSquare {
   position: absolute;
   left: 15px;
   top: 15px;
   width: 50%;
   height: 170px;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 }
 #rightTopblueSquare {
   height: 100%;
   width: 50%;
   position: relative;
   left: 50%;
   background-color: #7ab9c2;
   opacity: .99;
 }
 #leftBottomblueSquare {
   position: relative;
   top: -100%;
   height: 100%;
   width: 50%;
   background-color: #6baaae;
 }
 /*----------------------------------*/
 #greySquare {
   width: 50%;
   height: 170px;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 15px;
   left: 15px;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
 }
 #lefTopgreySquare {
   height: 100%;
   width: 50%;
   position: relative;
   left: 50%;
   background-color: #656f78;
 }
 #rightButtomgreySquare {
   position: relative;
   top: -100%;
   height: 100%;
   width: 50%;
   background-color: #313439;
 }
 /*----------------------------------*/
 #redSquare {
   width: 50%;
   height: 170px;
   position: absolute;
   right: 15px;
   bottom: 15px;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 }
 #leftBottomredSquare {
   height: 100%;
   width: 50%;
   position: relative;
   left: 50%;
   background-color: #a2191d;
 }
 #rightTopredSquare {
   position: relative;
   top: -100%;
   height: 100%;
   width: 50%;
   background-color: #d63030;
 }
 /*----------------------------------*/
 #orangeSquare {
   width: 50%;
   height: 170px;
   position: absolute;
   right: 15px;
   top: 15px;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
   z-index: -1;
 }
 #rightBottomorangeSquare {
   height: 100%;
   width: 50%;
   position: relative;
   left: 50%;
   background-color: #f42b06;
 }
 #lefttToporangeSquare {
   position: relative;
   top: -100%;
   height: 100%;
   width: 50%;
   background-color: #ff6a05;
   opacity: 1;
 }
```

```html
<div id="orangeSquare">
  <div id="rightBottomorangeSquare"></div>
  <div id="lefttToporangeSquare"></div>
</div>
<div id="redSquare">
  <div id="leftBottomredSquare"></div>
  <div id="rightTopredSquare"></div>
</div>
<div id="greySquare">
  <div id="lefTopgreySquare">leftTop</div>
  <div id="rightButtomgreySquare">rightBottom grey sqr</div>
</div>
<div id="blueSquare">
  <div id="rightTopblueSquare">rightTop</div>
  <div id="leftBottomblueSquare">LeftBotom blue sqr</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you need is not just changing z-index, what you need is real 3d transformation. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_3dtransforms.asp

Comment: tried, both div z-index:1;        and that div who position is higher be on top, no matter how do you spin it in all 3 dimentions X Y Z

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be accomplished using CSS 3D transforms. First, create an outer container and wrap your HTML in it:

```css
#outer {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    perspective: 1000px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

The outer container has a large perspective value to keep the elements from looking differently when we rotate them. It uses `transform-style: preserve-3d;` to override the default stacking engine and stack everything in a 3D context. This makes sure everything stacks properly.

Then, to get your elements to overlap properly just give each element a small twist of 5 degrees around the Y axis:

```
transform: ... rotateY(5deg);
```

Your alternate elements will get the opposite twist:

```
transform: ... rotateY(-5deg);
```

The result is a scene that makes sense in 3d, and that stacks exactly how it would in the physical world.

---

**Working, live example:**

```css
body {
   background-color: #222;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
 #blueSquare {
   position: absolute;
   left: 15px;
   top: 15px;
   width: 50%;
   height: 170px;
   -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-45deg) rotateY(5deg) ;
           transform: rotateZ(-45deg) rotateY(5deg) ;
 }
 #rightTopblueSquare {
   height: 100%;
   width: 50%;
   position: relative;
   left: 50%;
   background-color: #7ab9c2;
 }
 #leftBottomblueSquare {
   position: relative;
   top: -100%;
   height: 100%;
   width: 50%;
   background-color: #6baaae;
 }
 /*----------------------------------*/
 #greySquare {
   width: 50%;
   height: 170px;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 15px;
   left: 15px;
   -webkit-transform:rotateZ(45deg)  rotateY(-5deg) ;
           transform:rotateZ(45deg)  rotateY(-5deg) ;
 }
 #lefTopgreySquare {
   height: 100%;
   width: 50%;
   position: relative;
   left: 50%;
   background-color: #656f78;
 }
 #rightButtomgreySquare {
   position: relative;
   top: -100%;
   height: 100%;
   width: 50%;
   background-color: #313439;
 }
 /*----------------------------------*/
 #redSquare {
   width: 50%;
   height: 170px;
   position: absolute;
   right: 15px;
   bottom: 15px;
   -webkit-transform:  rotateZ(-45deg) rotateY(-5deg);
           transform:  rotateZ(-45deg) rotateY(-5deg);
 }
 #leftBottomredSquare {
   height: 100%;
   width: 50%;
   position: relative;
   left: 50%;
   background-color: #a2191d;
 }
 #rightTopredSquare {
   position: relative;
   top: -100%;
   height: 100%;
   width: 50%;
   background-color: #d63030;
 }
 /*----------------------------------*/
 #orangeSquare {
   width: 50%;
   height: 170px;
   position: absolute;
   right: 15px;
   top: 15px;
   -webkit-transform:  rotateZ(45deg) rotateY(5deg);
           transform:  rotateZ(45deg) rotateY(5deg);
 }
 #rightBottomorangeSquare {
   height: 100%;
   width: 50%;
   position: relative;
   left: 50%;
   background-color: #f42b06;
 }
 #lefttToporangeSquare {
   position: relative;
   top: -100%;
   height: 100%;
   width: 50%;
   background-color: #ff6a05;
 }

#outer {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
            perspective: 1000px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div id="orangeSquare">
      <div id="rightBottomorangeSquare"></div>
      <div id="lefttToporangeSquare"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="redSquare">
      <div id="leftBottomredSquare"></div>
      <div id="rightTopredSquare"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="greySquare">
      <div id="lefTopgreySquare">leftTop</div>
      <div id="rightButtomgreySquare">rightBottom grey sqr</div>
    </div>
    <div id="blueSquare">
      <div id="rightTopblueSquare">rightTop</div>
      <div id="leftBottomblueSquare">LeftBotom blue sqr</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/jjurL6j8/1/

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution  of this puzzle is duplicate last div and set opacity to him

There HTML and CSS code below:

```
<body>
 <div id="orangeSquare">
        <div id="rightBottomorangeSquare"></div>
        <div id="lefttToporangeSquare"></div>
    </div>
      <div id="orangeSquare2"> <!- this new line->
    <div id="rightBottomorangeSquare2"></div>
    <div id="lefttToporangeSquare2"></div>
      </div><!- this new line end->
    <div id="redSquare">
        <div id="leftBottomredSquare"></div>
        <div id="rightTopredSquare"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="greySquare">
        <div id="lefTopgreySquare">leftTop</div>
        <div id="rightButtomgreySquare">rightBottom grey sqr</div>
    </div>
    <div id="blueSquare">
        <div id="rightTopblueSquare">rightTop</div>
        <div id="leftBottomblueSquare">LeftBotom blue sqr</div>
    </div>
```

And added to the first CSS this piece of CSS code:

```
    #orangeSquare2 {
   width: 50%;
   height: 170px;
   position: absolute;
   right: 15px;
   top: 15px;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
   z-index: -1;
 }
 #rightBottomorangeSquare2 {
   height: 100%;
   width: 50%;
   position: relative;
   left: 50%;
   background-color: #f42b06;

 }
 #lefttToporangeSquare2 {
   position: relative;
   top: -100%;
   height: 100%;
   width: 50%;
   background-color: #ff6a05;
   opacity: 0;
 }
```

This works great =) and changing  with the size of windows
Here photo

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 0):

You could duplicate the orange square **partly** either by hardcoding it or by using some JS library. Then set a higher z-index than the blue square to it. If you crop it correctly it doesn't overlap the red square.

That's not a perfect solution and it causes other problems, i.e. if when text overlaps the borders of the duplicated and cropped element.

This technique is also used in older versions of Photoshop where it was not possible to create 3D elements.